# calling a stored procedure in sybase with an array from input parameter in java

Tags: java, sybase

Hi my Map `results = storedProcedure.execute(parameters);` is returning no data found in my DAO class, because 
my stored proc(in sybase) executes as below.

> execute file_sp('''123'',''234'',''566'',''223''')

any suggestions.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can expect a useful answer if you do not provide any further information.
But here's a suggestion: first figure out if the stored proc works correctly when you execute it directly(e.g. from 'isql').